# Faster double iteration over a single array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, numpy

I want to find a way to make faster the computation of the pairwise accuracy, that is going to compare elements of the same array (in this case it's a panda df column) computing their difference and then comparing the two results obtained. I would have a dataframe *df* with 3 column (*id* of the document, *Jugment* that represent the human evaluation and it's an int object, *PR_score* that represent the pagerank of that document and it's a float object) and i want to check if they agree on classifing one document better/worst of another one.

For example:

**id**: id1, id2, id3

**Jugment** : 1, 0, 0

**PR_score**: 0.18, 0.5, 0.12

in this case the two scores agree on classifing id1 better than id3, disagree on id1 and id2, and between id2 and id3 there is a human judgment tie, hence my pairwise accuracy is:

**agreement** = 1

**disagreement** = 1

**pairwise accuracy** =  agreement/ (agreement +disagreement) =1/2 = 0.5

This was my first solution's code, in which i used the column of the df as array (which help to reduce the computation time):

```
def pairwise(agree, disagree):
    return(agree/(agree+disagree))

def pairwise_computing_array(df):

    humanScores = np.array(df['Judgement'])  
    pagerankScores =  np.array(df['PR_Score']) 

    total = 0 
    agree = 0
    disagree = 0

    for i in range(len(df)-1):  
        for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
            total += 1
            human = humanScores[i] -  humanScores[j] #difference human judg
            if human != 0:
                pr = pagerankScores[i] -  pagerankScores[j]#difference pagerank score
                if pr != 0:
                    if np.sign(human) == np.sign(pr):  
                        agree += 1 #they agree in which of the two is better
                    else:
                        disagree +=1 #they do not agree in which of the two is better
                else:
                    continue;   
            else:
                continue;

    pairwise_accuracy = pairwise(agree, disagree)

    return(agree, disagree, total,  pairwise_accuracy)
```

I have try with a list comprehension in order to get a faster computation, but it's actually slower than the first solution:

```
def pairwise_computing_list_comprehension(df):

    humanScores = np.array(df['Judgement'])  
    pagerankScores =  np.array(judgmentPR['PR_Score']) 

    sign = [np.sign(pagerankScores[i] - pagerankScores[j]) == np.sign(humanScores[i] - humanScores[j] ) 
            for i in range(len(df)) for j in range(i+1, len(df)) 
                if (np.sign(pagerankScores[i] - pagerankScores[j]) != 0 
                    and np.sign(humanScores[i] - humanScores[j])!=0)]

    agreement = sum(sign)
    disagreement = len(sign) -  agreement                             
    pairwise_accuracy = pairwise(agreement, disagreement)

    return(agreement, disagreement, pairwise_accuracy)
```

I can't run on my entire dataset cause it takes too much time, i would like to have something that can be computed in less than 1 minutes ideally.

The computation over my computer of a small subset of 1000 row reached this performance:

code1:
1.57 s ± 3.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

code2:
3.51 s ± 10.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Your list-comprehension approach is going to be slower because it creates an unecessary list that you later have to sum over, plus, you re-calculate `pagerankScores[i] - pagerankScores[j]` several times. In any case, your first approach using a tool like [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) on raw, numeric `numpy.ndarray` objects is probably going to yield improvements, although, you are still going to be stuck with quadratic time complexity, since you are doing  pairwise comparison. Perhaps you can provide some sample data?

Comment: Fundamentally, iterating over `numpy.ndarray` objects using Python for-loops, especially using `for i in range(len(df)-1)` is going to be *slow*. Try using `list` objects and your first approach `df['Judgement'].values.tolist()` and you'll likely see significant improvements, but you can do better with `numba`

Comment: Thank you, I used your suggestion and it worked. I used my first approach with list instead of numpy array and i used as decorator jit from the numba packages before of the function `@jit(nopython = True)`. The final solution takes just few seconds for my entire dataset (58krow)

Comment: Use the numpy array if you are using `numba`!

Comment: @RobertaParisi Looking at the computations happening in `pairwise_computing_array(df)`, there would be no need for both `for` loops. Could you please provide a simple dataframe to work with?

Comment: @kmario23 [here you can find a sample of 100 row](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3lHqJ85Nm7jclpHT3RvUFpBWTVjTjlRMWtkNXN5QXlFRjZB), I don't know if there's a better way to share the file, if it's so please let me know. By the way I don't see how can you do this comparison with just one loop.

Comment: @RobertaParisi I added a partially vectorized code. Feel free to adapt it as per your need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that works in a reasonable amount of time, obtained thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga suggestion:

```py
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython = True)
def pairwise_computing(humanScores, pagerankScores):

    total = 0 
    agree = 0
    disagree = 0

    for i in range(len(humanScores)-1):  
        for j in range(i+1, len(humanScores)):
            total += 1
            human = humanScores[i] -  humanScores[j] #difference human judg
            if human != 0:
                pr = pagerankScores[i] -  pagerankScores[j]#difference pagerank score
                if pr != 0:
                    if np.sign(human) == np.sign(pr):  
                        agree += 1 #they agree in which of the two is better
                    else:
                        disagree +=1 #they do not agree in which of the two is better
                else:
                    continue   
            else:
                continue
    pairwise_accuracy = agree/(agree+disagree)
    return(agree, disagree, total,  pairwise_accuracy)
```

This are the time perfomance reached for my entire dataset (58k row):

7.98 s ± 2.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score 1):

You have numpy array, so why not just use it? You can offload the work from Python to C-compiled code (often, but not always):

First, resize the vectors into 1xN matrices:

```
humanScores = np.array(df['Judgement']).resize((1,-1))
pagerankScores =  np.array(judgmentPR['PR_Score']).resize((1,-1))
```

Then find the difference, and we are interested only on the sign:

```
humanDiff = (humanScores - humanScores.T).clip(-1,1)
pagerankDiff = (pagerankScores - pagerankScores.T).clip(-1,1)
```

Here I assumed the data are integers, so the `clip` function will only produce -1, 0, or 1. Then you can count it:

```
agree = ((humanDiff != 0) & (pagerankDiff != 0) & (humanDiff == pagerankDiff)).sum()
disagree = ((humanDiff != 0) & (pagerankDiff != 0) & (humanDiff != pagerankDiff)).sum()
```

But the above count is double-counting as item (i,j) and item (j,i) would be exact oppsite sign in both `humanDiff` and `pagerankDiff`. You may consider take only the upper-triangular part of the square matrix in the sum:

```
agree = ((humanDiff != 0) &
         (pagerankDiff != 0) &
         (np.triu(humanDiff) == np.triu(pagerankDiff))
        ).sum()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, like you could see in the example, the pagerankScore is float and not int. I tried your solution with some changes but still was too slow (but faster than my solution).

Comment: In that case you can try `np.sign(humanScores - humanScores.T)` to get -1, 0, or 1. But after all, you are checking N^2 pairs and you cannot be faster than O(N^2). One way to think about improvement is to sort your scores then find how many out-of-orders between humanScore and pagerankScore. That will be an algorithm change.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get rid of the inner `for` loop by leveraging broadcasting, since index `j` always ranges ahead of index `i` by 1 (i.e. we don't look back). But there is a slight problem with computing agreement/disagreement in the following line:

```
if np.sign(human) == np.sign(pr):
```

which I don't know how to resolve. So, I just provide the skeleton code here for more tweaking and making it to work, since you know the problem better. Here it goes:

```
def pairwise_computing_array(df):

    humanScores = df['Judgement'].values
    pagerankScores = df['PR_Score'].values 

    total = 0 
    agree = 0
    disagree = 0

    for i in range(len(df)-1):
        j = i+1
        human = humanScores[i] -  humanScores[j:]   #difference human judg
        human_mask = human != 0
        if np.sum(human_mask) > 0:  # check for at least one positive case
            pr = pagerankScores[i] -  pagerankScores[j:][human_mask]  #difference pagerank score
            pr_mask = pr !=0
            if np.sum(pr_mask) > 0:  # check for at least one positive case
                # TODO: issue arises here; how to resolve when (human.shape != pr.shape) ?
                # once this `if ... else` block is fixed, it's done
                if np.sign(human) == np.sign(pr):
                    agree += 1   #they agree in which of the two is better
                else:
                    disagree +=1   #they do not agree in which of the two is better
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
    pairwise_accuracy = pairwise(agree, disagree)

    return(agree, disagree, total,  pairwise_accuracy)
```

Comment: I tried using your solution and putting this outside of the for`compare = lambda x, y: np.sign(x)==np.sign(y)` and this inside
`unTied = np.intersect1d(np.where(human!=0), np.where(pr!=0))` , and after
`results = compare(human[unTied], pr[unTied])` . But it's slower than the other solution since it's not possible to use numba (a lot of the numpy function are not supported by numba)